# Append an entire form using jquery in an absolute position

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Just need to know how to append this entire html on a button click. I'm trying to create a list and display it over the page. .......................................................................................................................................

```
@Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { name = "vouchers", id = "vouchers" })
<h2>Voucher</h2>
<div class="whole">

<div class ="top">
    <label class ="lbl" >Assign a voucher Number </label>    
    <input type ="text" class="txt"/>

</div>
<div class="mid">
    <div class ="tdes">
    <table class="vtab">
             <tr class="heading">
            <td>
                Date 
            </td>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                Category
            </td>
            <td>
                Amount
            </td>
            <td>
                To Account
            </td>         
            </tr>
         @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr class="rows">

            <td>
                @item.Date.ToShortDateString()              
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Per)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amt)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AId)
            </td>
              </tr>
         }
    </table>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="bot">

    <input type ="submit" value="Save" class ="btn" id ="save" />
    <input type ="submit" value ="Print" class="btn" id ="print" />
</div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Well the easiest way would be `$('.button').on('click', function(){ $('#vouchers').load('ajax/test.html #container'); })` but you haven't told us if this form is already on the page you are trying to display it on or if needs to be requested via ajax?

Answer (score 0):

How about using jQuery UI Dialog:

```
$("#vouchers").dialog({
    autoShow: false,
    // Other options
});
$("#somebutton").click(function() {
    $("#vouchers").dialog("show");
});
```